# How to run a python command from inside a python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, environment-variables, s3cmd

I am running windows 7 x64 with python 2.7.6 and I just installed the s3cmd tool following these instructions: [s3cmd win7 installation](http://pixpuffindev.blogspot.gr/2012/07/setting-up-s3cmd-for-windows-for.html).

The problem is that while I have both the python directory and the python scripts on my path, I can't run s3cmd directly. So, if I fire a cmd and type:

`python` - it works!

However if I type

`s3cmd`

or

`python s3cmd`

they both fail even though my python scripts directory contains the file s3cmd:

In the case of s3cmd the error is `s3cmd is not recognized as external command or executable etc...` (I am translating here because the error is in a non-english locale). In the case of python s3cmd the error is: `python: can't open file 's3cmd': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.`

Ideally I'd like to run s3cmd from a python script I am writing and not call it directly from cmd, however I would be happy for any kind of input..!

Thanks.

Comment: *they both fail* - how?  What was the error message?

Comment: In the case of `s3cmd` the error is `s3cmd is not recognized as external command or executable` etc... (I am translating here because the error is in a non-english locale). In the case of `python s3cmd` the error is: `python: can't open file 's3cmd': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

Comment: OK, that means that `s3cmd` is not in the Windows path, and that you do not have a file called `s3cmd` in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you use the full path to s3cmd:

```
python C:\path to s3\s3cmd
```

If the path contains whitespace you might need to add Quotes:

```
python "C:\path to s3\s3cmd"
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this comment on their site:
You can create a batch script to run it by using the %* parameter, example:

> @python C:\s3\s3cmd %*

Have you tried it out yet?

Comment: It won't work. what does this command do exactly? What is the `@` symbol and what `%*` stands for?

Comment: @Konos5: the `@` means do not echo, and the `%*` means include all arguments to the .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages mean that the script `s3cmd` isn't on the path.

See this question for details: [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-xp)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on **Windows 2008 Server**:

- Setup python 2.x - **Python 3 is not supported**
- Download s3cmd from www.s3tools.org
- Add "C:\python2x\" to your global path
- Add "C:\Python2x\Scripts\" to your global path
- Run "python setup.py install" from s3cmd path (download path e.g: C:\Users\testuser\Downloads\S3cmd-1.6.0)
- Rename "C:\Python2x\Scripts\s3cmd" to "C:\Python2x\Scripts\s3cmd.py" **(Note: We are renaming "s3cmd" without any extension to "s3cmd.py")**
- Now you should be able to run "s3cmd.py" from anywhere :)